# Периодические просадки производительности при использовании linq к ConcurrentBag

Tags: c#, linq, производительность, tpl, plinq

Всем привет! Я пытаюсь разобраться с серьезными просадками производительности в приложении.

Просадки, про которые идет речь, появляются периодически. В основном итерации отрабатывают довольно быстро, но они разбавлены итерациями, которые занимают куда больше времени. Так как у приложения есть графическое отображение информации, это все выглядит очень дерганно и требует корректировки.

Пожалуйста, посмотрите на следующий код:

```
while (true)
{
    var rng = new Random(1);
    var concurrenBag = new ConcurrentBag<ICollection<(int X, int Y)>>();
    Parallel.For(0, 20000, i =>
    {
        var entry = new List<(int X, int Y)>(); // здесь демонстрируются основные аспекты реального алгоритма
        var r = rng.Next(0, 3);                 // примерно 20к обработчиков возвращают коллекцию пары координат
        for (var j = 0; j < r; j++)             // иногда возвращаются null'ы, иногда коллекция с 1 записью, чаще - с 2-мя
        {                                       // все возвращаемые обработчиками значения идут в ConcurrentBag
            entry.Add((j, j * j));
        }                         

        if (entry.Count == 0)     
            entry = null;         

        concurrenBag.Add(entry);  
    });

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var results = concurrenBag.ToList().AsParallel().Where(x => x != null).SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToList();  // как выяснилось, просадки в производительности ведут на эту строчку
    var time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    Console.WriteLine($"CB count: {concurrenBag.Count:00000}, result count: {results.Count:00}, time: {time:000}");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Указанный выше код приводит к следующему результату в консоли:

```
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 032        <- 32мс, для первой итерации с учетом инициализации и всего такого это норма        
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 004
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 014        <- 14мс, уже не норма
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 003
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 004
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 004
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 003
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 015        <- как видно, повторяется каждые несколько итераций
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 003
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 019
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 004
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 004
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 003
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 014
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 003
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 004
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 003
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 008
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 003
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 004
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 011
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 003
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 003
CB count: 20000, result count: 02, time: 004
```

Думаю, идея понятна. В реальном приложении каждая "нормальная" итерация занимает 10-15мс, а "просадочные" случаются каждые 6-8 итераций и занимают до 150мс

Изначально я предполагал что проблема могла быть с бизнес-логикой, но вы можете запустить приведенный выше пример и получите примерно те же резальтаты. Теперь я предполагаю что что-то не так с тем, как я использую `Parallel.For`, `AsParallel()` или `ConcurrentBag`, но я не представляю, что именно не так.

Comment: попробуйте убрать вот эту часть `.ToList().AsParallel()`

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за ответ! К сожалению, это не помогло. Периодические просадки по прежнему случаются. Только что запустил пример - обычная итерация идет ~2мс, и через каждые 6-8 одна итерация в ~13-14мс.

Comment: Зачем вам вообще ConcurrentBag? Чем не устроило `Enumerable.Range(...).AsParallel().SelectMany(...)?`

Comment: @PavelMayorov В реальном приложении я не просто беру 20к как литерал, там именно 20к обработчиков. Вот фрагмент кода, чисто для представления: `Parallel.For(0, preprocessed.Length, i => { var handler = preprocessed[i];...`

Comment: @DmitryVolkov так тем более! Делаете `preprocessed.AsParallel()` и поскакали! Зачем вообще вам нужен `Parallel.For`?

Comment: У вас тут счет идет на миллисекунды, так это может быть все. что угодно, например, GC. Попробуйте поставить `GC.Collect();` перед вашими измерениями (хотя это и не гарантирует ничего), ну и плюсую Павла

Comment: Спасибо за советы, сейчас попробую. Да, на англоязычном stackoverflow мне тоже писали про GC.

Comment: @DmitryVolkov Вывод на консоль тоже сделайте асинхронным. Синхронный вывод съедает часть процессорного времени в потоке, особенно это заметно на миллисекундах как у вас.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Но я замер делаю не всей итерации, а только одной строчки (без вывода в консоль)

Comment: @tym32167 Я проверил все озвученные тут гипотезы, и ваша гипотеза с GC действительно внесла ясность. Если вызывать `GC.Collect()`, то в целом производительность определенно падает, но та конкретная строчка отрабатывает стабильно и быстро. Но я не понимаю, ведь разве `value-tuple` не идет в стек, а GC управляет только кучей? И что бы вы могли в целом тут порекомендовать?

Comment: GC во время сборки мусора может стопать выполнение всего приложения, потому не важно, какие типы вы используете. Советовать тут нечего особо, пока не ясен ваш алгоритм - обычно, когда упираются в миллисекуды GC, то надо пересматривать ваш алгоритм и ваши структуры данных (я не советую играться с настройками GC, так как без понятия к чему это может привести)

Comment: @DmitryVolkov value-tuple идет туда где находится егр владелец. Любые контейнеры хранятся в куче, и value-tuple тут ничего не изменит.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Павел, спасибо за ваши комментарии. Один последний нюанс. Вы рекомендовали отказаться от Parallel.For в пользу PLinq'a. Это продиктовано производительностью, или какими-то негласными соглашениями? ConcurrentBag действительно замедляет работу Parallel.For'a по сравнению с PLinq'ом?

Comment: @DmitryVolkov ConcurrentBag - это лишняя сущность, которая занимает память. А чем больше памяти используется - тем чаще и дольше GC.